# How do I insert an image inside a <li> tag widthout getting the height of the <li> tag changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this mobile menu:

[image]

As you can see, the `<li>` tags with the image make the bottom expand a little bit, while "Boxing" which doesn't have any image inside the `<li>` tag doesn't. 
I tried "`height: 27px`" to the `<li>` tag. worked perfect. the problem is that when clicking the image - a submenu opens inside the `<li>` - when defining the height it doesn't expand.

This is how the html list item looks like:

```
                <ul class="sports">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <li url="http://google.com">NFL
                            <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   id="sub-menu" />
                            <ul class="sports2">
                                <a href="#" class="selected">
                                    <li>Superbowl</li>
                                </a>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </a>

// one without an image: 

                    <a href="#"><li> Boxing</li></a>
```

and this is my css:

```
.sports li{
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*height: 27px;*/
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Use a background image, which would be more semantic anyway?

Comment: Just change the height to auto when you click the menu so it will expand with the newly displayed content and change back to 27px when the menu is closed do this using javascript...

Comment: Tried using a background image inside a div instead of an <img> tag. does the same spacing. 

using height:auto doesn't work and leave it as it is.

Comment: That's what `background-position` is for

Comment: but I cant use it on the LI background - it's a button that opens the sub-items list..

Answer (score 0):

Give Max-height to the image that way it will not get bigger tha tthe li

```
li > img{
max-height:100%;
}
```

i hope it works

Comment: I'll try it in a second :)

Comment: doesn't work :(

I tried  .sports li > img{
  max-height:100%;
 } too.

Comment: Just read your post again, Do you want to try just another thing insted of 100% give max-height 27px or what ever size your li is going to be when not expanded.